# Are there guidelines/suggestions/etc. for how quickly to edit a question?

Tags: discussion, edits

In many cases when someone first posts a question they don't get the formatting correct.

Many people notice this and go in to correct the formatting themselves, but many people do not.

My question is how quickly should someone jump on the edit to fix the formatting?

What sort of grace period should we be giving the initial questioner to notice and improve their own question?

Should we be trying to encourage people to improve their own formatting or just fixing it for them and moving on?

I find myself torn on this issue, but I generally try to give them at least a minute or two before I edit for formatting; then again I've seen questions go much longer than that without being fixed, and many being fixed within seconds. (Mea culpa; I didn't pay attention to view counts on the questions that had gone a long time without editing to see what that number looked like.)

Comment: It's less work on everyone if you just go ahead and fix it rather than waiting. Be sure to fix anything else that is wrong while you're there.

Comment: @KevinB Less work assuming no one collides, but yes in some/many senses I agree that it is less work. The crux of my question is is avoiding that work the primary goal in this decision.

Comment: For me it is, but i guess that's just one person's opinion. seems like you're looking for more of a consensus.

Comment: @KevinB I'm curious as to whether there was a consensus (or even just a general trend to the breeze of opinion). I'm not searching for **one** answer. I'm not even necessarily searching for arguments to help me make my decision (though that's certainly part of why I thought of the question).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As a philosophical matter, there's no reason at all to wait -- the poster had all the time in the world before publishing to preview the post; the version that appears should be what she intended to share.

Practically speaking, of course, in the real world, we all make mistakes. I usually like to give the poster the [full five-minute grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9090/is-there-an-editing-grace-period-on-answers-after-they-have-been-posted) before I step in to edit. That's generally when the most "oops, missed the formatting there", "oh, didn't mean to use that word" edits take place, and the edit conflicts otherwise just end up being annoying for both of us.

I recommend waiting for about five minutes after *anyone* has made a revision to a post, just to be sure that no further changes are coming.*

---

*Myself, I sometimes even make a quick tag-only edit to a question before editing the body, with the idea that others may likewise give me a few minutes to make further changes.

Comment: Anyone who happens to be hanging around on this page may notice that I've taken advantage of the grace period myself to reword a couple of things here, belying my first sentence.

Comment: That's a fair point about the time before posting but I know that in some of the windows and font sizes I've read this site on the preview area (at least for answers) was scrolled off the bottom of the window so I didn't see it live. If that happens to the poster (which is less likely than to an answerer, I grant) and the poster scrolls quickly and clicks they may never see the preview. This seems especially likely in the case where the input text is wrapped from many lines to relatively few lines so the comparable sizes of the input and preview areas are incorrectly prioritized for scanning.

Answer (score 15):

You're free to do whatever you want.

- If you want to edit the post immediately, that's fine.
- If you want to wait a bit and then edit, that's also fine.
- If you want to not bother editing, that's fine.

Comment: I wasn't intending to suggest that any of those behaviors was incorrect. I was wondering if there is a general sense/guideline on what the *most* correct of those choices would be.

Comment: @EtanReisner They're all equally correct.

Comment: They clearly don't all have the same teaching effects (if nothing else) and so asserting they are fully equivalent means asserting that the teaching effects of allowing a person to notice their own mistakes and/or commenting about the mistakes and letting the person fix them have no value. You are certainly welcome to that view. I'm not sure I share it and I'm even less sure that the network as a whole shares it (in that I know I at least partly disagree with it, I hold no knowledge about what the network believes... hence the question).

Comment: @EtanReisner There's also value in having a post be more correct sooner.  There's value in not having to wait around and remember to make edits to a post when you notice the mistake, and risk forgetting about it.  Honestly if the user was going to go back and edit the post right away anyway then they didn't *need* the teaching moment.  It's the people that won't have gone back and edit the post even if you don't edit it that are the one's that need the teaching moment.

Comment: Yes, there are values to all the positions. That's the crux of my question. Are the certain values that the network prefers in this situation. And no, I think it is an unnecessarily uncharitable view to assume that no one who *immediately* (fsdo immediate) edits is going to notice and edit. It may be true in practice but I think using that as the initial assumption is unhelpful. (If true in practice then that certainly impacts the editor behavior though. I wonder if this is something that could be data mined in a meaningful way.)

Comment: @EtanReisner If you personally want to wait, that's *just fine*.  People aren't going to be chewing you out because you dared to wait 5 minutes before editing.  Likewise, you're more than welcome to edit the post as soon as you notice a problem, without waiting.  You are not going to be chastized for doing so.  You may run into editing conflicts every now and then (I edit a lot of posts, and I never wait, and editing conflicts are still fairly rare for me) but those conflicts aren't particularly difficult to sort out.  Do whatever you want without being concerned with what other people want.

Comment: I expressed no concern. I didn't worry about getting yelled at or down-voted or criticized. None of that was the point. The point was, and remains, a question about the values the network wishes to promote and whether there is a general sense of in which direction those push this decision. I tagged this discussion for a reason.

Comment: @EtanReisner And again, I'm telling you that the community does not particularly value one over the other.  All are welcomed.  You seem to be under the impression that the community *must* feel that one is best.  That just isn't the case.

Comment: I can't assert that the network doesn't have an opinion. I solicited one. You seem to feel very strongly that the network has no such opinion. That's fine. You seem to be bothered by the fact that I'm not simply taking your assertion and moving on and I'm not sure why that would bother you so (even if you happen to be correct about this fact). The nature of a question of this sort is that a single answer (short of one that is documented canonically.) can never be simply accepted as *the* answer. All I feel is that members of the community might have opinions and I wish to understand/hear them.

Comment: @EtanReisner, I think you are seeing "bothered" where the intent, as it seems to me from over here, is expressing and defending his answer. Personally, I agree with him.  I believe you are mistaken in seeing any degree of distress on the part of Servy.

Comment: Shog's edit is the highlight of this answer!

Comment: Sure, everything's "fine". But which is preferable from the point of view of quality and the community? Isn't that the spirit of the question? In an overwhelming majority of cases (not 100%, but way more than 50%), editing is preferable to not editing. So I disagree with this answer, because I think it misses the point.

Answer (score 9):

I find that the original poster often doesn't notice / care about / know how to fix simple formatting errors. Remember that the preview of the question shows up as you enter it... so you would assume a person doesn't wait until after they have submitted their post to say "oh dear I didn't use code blocks. I better go in and fix that". They just don't know.

So my take is - if you see a problem, go in and fix it. Especially if it's not major. Big edits - the ones where you may spend five minutes, only to find that someone "has already edited; your edit will only be accepted if it's more substantive" (or whatever the message is) - those I tend to wait a little longer.

I wish there was a feature where you could "check out" a question for editing. "I got this. Don't mess with it - wait for my edits". That way you don't have two or three people editing the same thing. Maybe that's a topic for another meta post.

I am less forgiving with questions that have a lot wrong these days. I might just leave a comment explaining how much is wrong, and how to go about fixing - and move on. No point putting a train wreck back together unless the underlying question is really interesting and the OP is either very new, or clearly not an English speaker.

You asked for a sense of the direction of opinions - here's mine.

Answer (score 4):

### If and when you see the need and feel the urge, edit.

That's how quickly. Anything else is just unmanageable hand-wringing.

Where appropriate, add a comment to educate the OP, with an intimation to DIY next time e.g.

> Please format your code as `code` using the curly brace `{}` button. Did it for you this time.